# Rest concepts can be applied to Non-Web applications?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am learning Rest web Services. When I am learning basics of Rest I cam across the Real Rest meaning i.e  Rest is an architectural style which defines set of guidelines for building any applications .

If rest guide concepts applied to web Service then webservices are called as RestFul web services.

My question is other than web services for which applications REST concepts can be applied? Can it be applied for non- web applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the introduction to Chapter 5 in Roy Fielding's doctoral dissertation on REST (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), he describes REST as an

> architectural style for distributed hypermedia systems... REST is a hybrid style derived from several of the network-based architectural styles described in Chapter 3 and combined with additional constraints that define a uniform connector interface.

He then goes on to describe various constraints for REST, including that it be client-server based, stateless, describe cacheable/non-cacheable, and have a uniform interface.

So really, any networked application transferring hypermedia (which is pretty broad and includes graphics, audio, text, links, etc. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermedia) could have concepts from REST applied to it.  In my experience, people will still refer to those applications as "web services," even if they're just designed for communication between specific endpoints rather than for consumption of the larger web in general.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One more doubt is even though Rest has constraints still Rest is explained as it does not have any rules no service definition? I am confused with this statement that Rest need not follow any rule

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're referring to.  REST certainly has rules that have to be followed in order to create a REST-ful service, but outside those constraints, you do have leeway in how you decide to design and implement your service.